# Making ajax request in MVC and calling ADAL

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, adal, onenote-api

I have a requirement to call an action from a view. I have two ways of doing it:

1. By using ajax
2. By using HTML.ActionLink

I want to use ajax for some specific reasons. Now the issue is, the action which I am calling is using ADAL and therefore, after authorization from Azure AD, it redirects to return URI specified there (using RedirectResult in MVC). Check [this link](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2013/10/29/using-adals-acquiretokenby-authorizationcode-to-call-a-web-api-from-a-web-app/) for complete ADAL code.

Now the issue is, the whole process works fine if I am using option 2 i.e. `HTML.ActionLink` but doesn't work with ajax. In ajax, it never reach the return uri (which is `CatchCode` function if you check the link mentioned above) specified in azure AD, though, in fiddler the url is formed same for both the options.

Any help? I hope I made sense.

Edit:
Ajax code I am using is

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/Home/About',
        data: { id: someKey },
        cache: false,
        type: "POST",
        success: function (data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
            //dosomething
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            //dosomething
            console.log(errorThrown);
        },
        complete: function () {
            //dosomething
        }
    });
```

Comment: My friend, I think we need code in order to help you :)

Comment: The C# code for ADAL is same as present in the link. I have edited the question for ajax. It is pretty much straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

@Garima, This isn't a OneNote specific question and I am not an expert in AAD Auth but I'll try my best to answer. Are you using response_type 'code' when making the OAuth call? If so, you've implemented the OAuth Authorization Code grant flow which will work great from server side. If you want to do OAuth from the client (aka Ajax) you will need to implement the OAuth client credentials grant flow.
You can read about the 2 flows at:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn645543.aspx
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn645542.aspx

Try using the client credentials grant flow for ajax.

Comment: Agree Dipak it is not one note specific question but I am trying this for making calls to one note api and hence the tag. Thanks for your reply. I will look into the links.